# Is there such a thing as an Even Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, even-and-odd-functions

An even function is one in which $f(x)=f(-x)$.

For two variables I believe this is $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$

If I wish to make a 2D even matrix how would I do this?

$$ \begin{matrix} (0,0) & (0,1) \\
                  (1,0) & (1,1) \end{matrix}$$

Looking at the indices I can't see any pattern that would allow a even matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are looking for a linear transformation $T : V \to W$ such that $T(u) = T(-u)$, or equivalently that $T(u) - T(-u) = 0$. Since $T$ is linear, we have
\begin{align}
T(u) - T(-u) &= T(u) + T(u) \\
&= T(u + u) \\
&= 2T(u),
\end{align} 
so we are looking for $T$ such that for all $u \in V$, $2T(u) = 0$, i.e., 
$$
T(u) = 0.
$$
Only one such transformation exists, namely: $T = 0$.

Comment: So there's only a trivial version in which the matrix is all zeros?

Comment: Exactly. Incidentally, this is a great example for when using the abstract notions of linear algebra *greatly* clarifies the specific $\mathbb{R}^2$ case you were considering.